# How to let others refresh Excel report with external connection to database, like Oracle without having individual database credentials?

Tags: excel, oracle

I've created Excel report for my colleagues where data is directly pulled from the Oracle database. I have no issue to access and refresh data when putting my credentials to the Oracle driver connector in Excel.

However, Excel asks my colleagues for database credentials when refreshing the first time. Since it's pretty cumbersome for IT team to set individual credentials for 300 users, what could be the workaround that? I heard about Microsoft Secure Store Service with Application id, but it's probably outdated, is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a single new Oracle user.
2. `GRANT` that new Oracle user the `SELECT` privilege on the tables that they need to access from the other user that owns the tables.
3. `GRANT` that new Oracle user the appropriate privileges so that users can connect to that user and login to the database.
4. Give those credentials to all the other users and have everyone connect as the same user who only has read privileges on the data.
5. Modify your SQL so that you always use `SELECT ... FROM schema_name.table_name ...` so that users are selecting data from the correct schema (i.e. the one that owns the data and not the local schema they are connecting to).